# What is the exact difference between Rack and Rails Metal in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

I am newbie to Rack and Rails metal, can anyone tell me which situation has to use which?. According to my understanding both Rack and Metal to filter/bypass http request and response. Need a better clarification, when to use what?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Rails Metal has been [removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ed34652d1aca148fea61c5309c1bd5ff3a55abfa) from Rails 3 a long time ago. Basically it used to be a thin wrapper around Rack that could act more like an endpoint rather than a filter (which is usually the case with Rack middleware). Check this post for a more detailed explanation: http://jnewland.github.io/articles/2008/12/16/rails-metal-a-micro-framework-with-the-power-of-rails-m/

Nowadays, as an alternative, what you can use is [ActionController::Metal](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html) which is  a very lightweight controller that can provide very fast responses without offering many of the "cool" Rails stuff.

As far as Rack is concerned it is basically:

> a minimal interface between webservers supporting Ruby and Ruby frameworks.

So it basically helps standardize the communication between any webserver that supports Ruby with any possible Ruby web framework.

Here is a nice schematic representation of what Rack does taken from [Passenger's docs](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Architectural%20overview.html#_ruby_rack_and_ruby_on_rails)
[image]