# How Metal is different than Rack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I just watched Railscasts #150 Rails Metal and I got a question to ask.

How Metal is different than Rack? Is Metal just Rails effort to be Rack compatible? And when to use what?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Here is I found a good answer on my question.

[What is the exact difference between Rack and Rails Metal in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603658/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-rack-and-rails-metal-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 1):

Metal is / was supposed to be a subset of Rack. It had the same rack interface for compatibility purposes.
I think Rails was reverted back to use rack in version 3, so you won't find much about metal anymore.